# How to create a password reset system for accounts with no external communication method attached?

Tags: passwords

If user accounts are identified only by a username, and have no email or phone number attached to them by design, then what are my options for password reset flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of individual recovery key - like a secret question, or a recovery code created during account creation - is probably your only option.

The natural consequence of this is that if your users lose or forget these recovery keys, *their account cannot be recovered*. But since you've got no additional identifiers by design, this will probably be an acceptable (or at least unsurprising) trade-off for your users.